# Unable to process form fields in ajax with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 7 and PHP 7.4. I'm submitting my form using ajax call and getting a Json response to show the relevant errors, if any.

I `serialize()` the form in the ajax call. My issue is that I'm getting `422 Unprocessable Entity` against each field I applied validation to.

Surprising thing is that if my field is not empty, I still get **required** error that's weird.

I found the fact that people who have faced this issue in past, either have switched to another approach or got a solution by hit and trial method.  My validation is according to Laravel doc.

Why am I getting this error and what's the proper solution?

Blade view

```html
<form method="POST" name="register_name" id="register_forms" action="{{ route('verifydata') }}">
    @csrf
    <input placeholder="Name" id="register_name" type="text" />
    <input id="my-register" type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Javascript

```js
$("#my-register").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    var data = $('#register_forms').serialize()
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "{{ url('verifydata') }}",
        data: {
            _token: _token,
            data: data
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data.message);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            if (err.status == 422) { // when status code is 422, it's a validation issue
                console.log(err.responseJSON);
                $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(err.responseJSON.message);

                console.warn(err.responseJSON.errors);
                $.each(err.responseJSON.errors, function(i, error) {
                    var el = $(document).find('[name="' + i + '"]');
                    el.after($('<span style="color: red;">' + error[0] + '</span>'));
                });
            }
        }
    });
    /**Ajax code ends**/
});
```

Controller

```php
public function verifydata(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',
    ]);

    $name = $request->register_name;

    return response()->json([
        'message' => $name
    ]);
}
```

Comment: `'name' => 'required', 'string', 'max:255',` should probably be an array `'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255']` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

Comment: @kerbh0lz
It's still saying "422 Unprocessable Entity".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to understand what error you are getting, so read this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.

I see three errors:

First: You are telling in your request, that you are sending JSON data, which is not true

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Because **.serialize()** is not generating JSON, but serialized POST body

IT looks like: **name=kamil&surname=kamil**

So, remove dataType: 'json' and add this to **data**

```
data : $('#register_forms').serialize() + "&_token=" + _token
```

If you want to send JSON data, you need to create JSON data.

Sedcond: You don't have "name" attribute in your "inputs".

```
<form method="POST" name="register_name" id="register_forms" action="{{ route('verifydata') }}">
    <input placeholder="Name" name="register_name" id="register_name" type="text" />
    <input id="my-register" type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Three: in your PHP code, where you need to specify validation rules like this

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation

So, this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
]);
```

Or, this

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
]);
```

After fixing this, it should work.

Comment: Just an FYI, according to the  [$.ajax docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)  `dataType` is for the response not the request. :)

Comment: True, If I want to get json response, I would have to define dataType:json.

Comment: I just added this line "
data : $('#register_forms').serialize() + "&_token=" + _token,"
and my 50% issue is resolved and that's If my field has value then ajax returns 200 ok status. 
........
Now the issue is when I leave field empty then it returns error "422 Unprocessable Entity" meaning that my validation is not working !

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with the code you've provided.

You've not provided a `name` attribute to your `<input />`. Change your `<input />` to be:

```
<input name="name" placeholder="Name" id="register_name" type="text"/>
```

---

Assign the serialized data directly to the `data` attribute rather than inside an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "{{ url('verifydata') }}",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
});
```

The code you current have (assuming the input field has a name) would result in the following on the server:

```
[
    '_token' => 'cqmRx74gJiSXyAFXBdq5UagX68O6OvYqX67WwIAZ',
    'data'   => '_token=cqmRx74gJiSXyAFXBdq5UagX68O6OvYqX67WwIAZ&name=foobar' 
]
```

The serialized data will not get parsed if it's a child attribute of the body.

Also, you don't need to add the `_token` attribute as it should already included in your form since you've used `@csrf`.

---

Lastly, either wrap you validation rules in an array:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
]);
```

or a single string separated by pipes (`|`):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:255'],
]);
```

Comment: I took all of your recommended steps. I just removed the token from my ajax call and it started to give an error "Status Code: 419 unknown status". 
After adding token, my issue is back so I think token is compulsory here.

Comment: @Shaan Did you remove the `@csrf` directive from the form? If so, you'll need to put it back.

Comment: No, I just removed the _token as per your instruction from my ajax call. @csrf was there in my code and I got the error as I said.

Comment: @Shaan Oh, that's weird. I've just tested it locally and it should work fine since `@csrf` will add the `_token` field to your form and `serialize()` should include that data as well. I would suggest checking the network tab in your browser to make sure it isn't being included. If it is, that you will probably need to do a hard refresh.

Comment: @Shaan ...alternatively, you could instead include the token as a header: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-toke

Comment: May be  you are right but I have been facing this issue a few days back and after including the token in ajax request, my all ajax calls works fine now so I think token is compulsory. 
Moral of story is my issue is still there :(

Comment: @Shaan You're definitely right, the `_token` is required with Laravel (unless you explicitly disable csrf protection for the route or include it as a header). My point is I can't see any reason why the `_token` field isn't being included in the serialized data considering your using `@csrf` directive inside the `<form>`. Very strange. Anyway, best of luck! :)